# how can I upgrade to 15.04 if the required 'Saucy' dir does not exist

Tags: 13.10, updates, 15.04

when updating to 15.04 from 14.04 Iget the follwing errors

```
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von http : // us.archive.ubuntu.com / ubuntu/dists   / saucy / universe / source / Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::17 80]
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von http : // us.archive.ubuntu.com / ubuntu / dists / saucy / multiverse / source / Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::17 80]
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von http : // us.archive.ubuntu.com / ubuntu / dists / saucy-updates / universe / source / Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::17 80]
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von http : // us.archive.ubuntu.com / ubuntu / dists / saucy-updates / multiverse / source / Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::17 80]
E:Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

and ubuntu reverts to 14.04

the 'saucy' directory actually does not exist at the given address

what do I do now?

Comment: Please add the output of `lsb_release -cd`.

Comment: try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories).

Comment: Please provide the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the main server, eg: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy universe`.

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's://us\.://:g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: 3* upvoted question and no one upvoted the answer...  :-(

Comment: @Fabby Maybe the answer is wrong?